# What does `decode112with18` do?

Tags: solidity, fixed-point

In a Solidity fixed point [library](https://github.com/compound-finance/open-oracle/blob/d0a0d0301bff08457d9dfc5861080d3124d079cd/contracts/Uniswap/UniswapLib.sol#L27), the function `decode112with18` converts a uq112x112 to a uint value and I'm wondering what exactly is happening in the function. Thanks.

```
    // decode a uq112x112 into a uint with 18 decimals of precision
    function decode112with18(uq112x112 memory self) internal pure returns (uint) {
        return uint(self._x) / 5192296858534827;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The uq112x112 library you linked encodes numbers this way :

```
// returns a uq112x112 which represents the ratio of the numerator to the denominator
// equivalent to encode(numerator).div(denominator)
function fraction(uint112 numerator, uint112 denominator) internal pure returns (uq112x112 memory) {
    require(denominator > 0, "FixedPoint: DIV_BY_ZERO");
    return uq112x112((uint224(numerator) << 112) / denominator);
}
```

So a fraction `a/b` is encoded as `(a << 112) / b` or `(a * 2^112) / b`.
Also equivalent to : `(a/b) * 2^112`. But obviously the last notation would lead to precision loss on (a/b) before scaling, so we stick with the 2 firsts ones : scaling before division.

We will note `(a/b) * 2^112` as `x`.

To get back to an integer with 18 decimals of precision, you obviously need to multiply your number by `1e18` and to undo the scaling of `2^112`.

So we must compute `(x * 1e18) / 2^112`

But `1e18` = `1000000000000000000` or `2^(log2(1e18))` : `around 2^(59.79)`

Rewriting this, we get : `(x * 2^log2(1e18)) / 2^112`
Or : `x / 2^(112 - log2(1e18))`

Turns out that `2^(112 - log2(1e18))` is roughly equal to : `5192296858534816` (truncated and rounded)

So our previous notation is equivalent to : `x / 5192296858534816` to get back an integer notation with 18 decimals of precision.

With `x` = `(a/b) * 2^112`, this is all that `uint(self._x) / 5192296858534827;` does.

It's just replacing some mathematical expressions by their numeric values.

Comment: This is very nice. Very detailed. Just would like to add one llittle point that rewriting `(x * 1e18)/2^112` to `x/2^(112-log2(1e18))` is not only for mathematical convenience, but also a must because otherwise `x * 1e18` will cause overflow.

Comment: You are right, I started explaining the comment from the link "// we only have 256 - 224 = 32 bits to spare, so scaling up by ~60 bits is dangerous" but forgot it, thanks for pointing that out !

Comment: I think the operations can be described in a plain language as to convert a uq112x112 to a uint256, the original number must right shift 112 digits to remove all the decimal digits. To keep 18 decimals of precision, the number from the previous step must left shift `log2(1e18)` digits, so the net effect is right shift `112-log2(1e18)` or roughly 52 digits, however, due to rounding errors, it would be better to use division that can fine-tune better.

Comment: Hmmm if you absolutely want to do it in 2 steps, I think that you must do the left shift `log2(1e18)` first (as long as you have enough bits to spare). If you do the right shift first, you risk losing precision immediately due to rounding errors. But anyway it's the same overall idea.

Comment: Yes, I was just talking heuristically if I were talking to a classroom of students.